# DD-MM-YYYY date format possible for input in orbeon?

Tags: date, input, datepicker, orbeon, xforms

I use Orbeon Forms and i have a calendar input.

When i pick up a date, it shows me the date in american format: MM/DD/YYYY.
For example i have 1/27/2015!

How can the input show the date in european format DD/MM/YYYY? Like 27/01/2015

I've tried without success:

```
<!-- Main instance -->
...
</StartOfWork>
...

<!-- Bindings -->
...
<xf:bind id="startOfWork-bind" ref="FormData/Payload/Project/Payment/StartOfWork"
                             name="startOfWork" type="xf:date"/>
...

...<fr:view>
...
<xf:input id="startOfWork-control" bind="startOfWork-bind" class="" date="[D]/[M]/[Y]">
        <xf:label ref="$form-resources/startOfWork/label"/>
        <xf:hint ref="$form-resources/startOfWork/hint"/>
        <xf:alert ref="$fr-resources/detail/labels/alert"/>
        </xf:input>
...</fr:view>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, by setting the `oxf.xforms.format.input.date` property to `[D]/[M]/[Y]`, as in:

```
<property as="xs:string"  
          name="oxf.xforms.format.input.date"  
          value="[D]/[M]/[Y]"/>
```

And you can find more on other supported values in the [documentation for that property](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/properties/xforms.html#for-xfinput).

Comment: From the documentation: "To override properties, you create one of the following files under your web app's WEB-INF/resources/config: properties-local.xml"...Instead of this way, isn't another tha we can do?Something from the code?
 Can i do something like this? ... <xf:input id="startOfWork-control" bind="startOfWork-bind" class="" date="[D]/[M]/[Y]"> ...</fr:view>

Comment: You can't override this at the control level, but you can at the form level, by adding on the first `xf:model` in your form an attribute `xxf:format.input.date="…"`. And BTW, this will work for all the XForms properties, i.e. those starting with `oxf.xforms`.